# How to generate or compile flutter gRPC .proto file in dart

Tags: flutter, dart, grpc, dart-pub, proto

I'm trying to generated proto file to dart file with protoc-plugin follow this instruction https://grpc.io/docs/quickstart/dart/ but when I run this command line

```
$ protoc --dart_out=grpc:lib/src/generated -Iprotos protos/helloworld.proto
```

this type of error occure

```
PS G:\Flutter Implelemt\helloworld> protoc --dart_out=grpc:lib/src/generated -Iprotos 
protos/helloworld.proto
protos: warning: directory does not exist.
Could not make proto path relative: protos/helloworld.proto: No such file or directory
PS G:\Flutter Implelemt\helloworld>
```

**dependencies used**

```
grpc: ^0.6.6
protobuf: ^1.1.0
protoc_plugin: ^19.2.0+1
```

**helloworld.proto**

```
syntax = "proto3";
package helloworld;

service  Greeter  { 
       rpc  SayHello  ( HelloRequest )  returns  ( HelloReply )  {} 
  }

  message  HelloRequest  { 
      string  name  =  1 ; 
    }

  message  HelloReply  { 
       string  message  =  1 ; 
  }
```

*I also try the following commands*

```
PS G:\Flutter Implelemt\helloworld> protoc --dart_out=grpc:lib/src/pb --proto_path 
lib/protos/helloworld.proto  
Missing input file.
PS G:\Flutter Implelemt\helloworld>
```

**how to generate or compile the .proto file in dart/flutter**

*Thanks in advance :)*

Comment: Hi, did you solve your problem?

Answer (score 2):

**Update**

I solve the above problem

note: I am using windows 10 OS with VSCode editor

*Steps to solve*

**1.** Install Dart

**2** Install the protocol compiler plugin for Dart (protoc-gen-dart) using the following command:

```
pub global activate protoc_plugin
```

**3** Update your PATH so that the protoc compiler can find the plugin:

- open environment variables
- C:\Users[User Name]\AppData\Local\Pub\Cache\bin

**4** change directory to lib folder and run the following commands

- paste your proto folder in lib directory
- like this *flutterProjectName/lib/protos/protoFileName.proto*

  ```
   protoc --dart_out=grpc:src/generated -Iprotos protos/helloworld.proto
  ```

in case if you see this error `file missing or file not found then replace this **-Iprotos** name with **--proto_path**`

**Note:** if you see the error like binary something like this, then try the following method

```
flutter pub cache repair
```

or delete *Cache* folder in this directory *C:\Users[User Name]\AppData\Local\Pub\Cache\bin*

if all the above things fail delete the cache folder or also check the version updated in the lock file (some time lock give me the problem with updating the version number)

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Make sure your output directory exists, and your input file relative path is correct. See your error message:

```
protos: warning: directory does not exist.
Could not make proto path relative: protos/helloworld.proto: No such file or directory
```

we can know that, the `protos/helloworld.proto` seems to not exist.